# Как динамически менять экран игры с разрешением, несовпадающим с разрешением устройства libgdx scene2d

Tags: libgdx

Здравствуйте! Имею игровой экран в libgdx scene2d. Хочу, чтобы разрешение экрана игры было, например, 400x600. Это можно сделать, если использовать OrthographicCamera(400, 600). Но когда я использую Stage и добавляю камеру через setCamera, то перестаёт работать метод hit у классов Actor,  который отвечает за нажатия на экран. Помогите, как решить эту проблему правильно?

Comment: Нужно передавать в конструктор Stage вьюпорт с размерами 400x600.

Answer (score 0):

Сам только постигаю возможности LibGDX. Я думаю вам не надо устанавливать камеру для Stage, так как там уже есть своя. Вам надо создать Viewport и потом передать его в конструктор Stage вместе с Batch. Когда создаете Viewport, то выбираете какой именно создать (с сохранением пропорций, или растягивающийся) и передадите в конструктор Viewport нужные размеры в пикселях или единицах мира. Лучше в единицах мира.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, вы забыли добавить stage в слушатели

```
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
```